# Perl Net::Jabber::Bot new line

Tags: perl, xmpp, newline

I'm using `Net::Jabber::Bot` module in my Perl script and it works properly but one problem is that when I want to send a message all new lines get removed! Two questions :

1. How we can have new lines in our messages? Should we disable a`chomp` somewhere?
2. What happens with new lines in Jabber/XMPP?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue, somebody already submitted a patch for this: http://code.google.com/p/perl-net-jabber-bot/issues/detail?id=24

You are not able to send \n directly but you maybe able to send xmpp/jabber coded newline if that code does not contain unprintable chars.

In this sub:

```
sub _send_individual_message {
...
# Strip out anything that's not a printable character
# Now with unicode support?
$message_chunk =~ s/[^[:print:]]+/./xmsg;
```

Comment: There is no problem with newlines in normal messages.  The quoted text refers to data forms.